# Given that $a_n < \frac{1}{2} (a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})$ and $a_n>0$. Show that $(a_n )$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the following exercise:

> Given $a_n$ a sequence of positive real numbers such that$$a_n <\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}2$$prove that $a_n$ converges.

My idea is to prove that $a_n$ is a bounded sequence and that is (I hope) quite easy to show because it can be possible to find an upper bound for $a_n$ writing a series of strictly inequalities and I showed that$$a_n <\frac{2^{n-N_0}a_{N_0}+\text{something}}{2^{n-N_0}}$$where $N_0$ is the natural number for that my sequence has that relation between $a_n$ and the two terms before. How can I prove now that $a_n$ is convergent?